# TypeScript 'this.' doesn't set object

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm using Bing maps v8 to do geocoding. 
at first this code was not in a class. I've ended up adding the code in a class, because of this error:

```
typescript cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'map'
```

Because I'm using a class now I'm having problems with 'this.'. 
After reading about ['this' in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript), I've changed my functions using Instance functions (instance arrow functions):

```
/// <reference path="./../scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./../scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Modules/Search.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./../scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

class BMGeocode {

    map: Microsoft.Maps.Map;
    searchManager: Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager;

    public loadMap = () => {
        this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#map', {
            credentials: 'xxx',
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.087299, 2.976770),
            zoom: 10
        });
    }

    public search = () => {
        if (!this.searchManager) {
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                this.searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(this.map) ; // PROBLEM: searchManager is never set?
            });
        }

        // remove any previous results from the map.
        this.map.entities.clear();

        // get the users query and geocode it.
        let query: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txtInput")).value;
        this.geocodeQuery(query);
    }

    private geocodeQuery = (query: string) => {
        var userData = { name: 'Maps Test User', id: 'XYZ' };
        let searchRequest: Microsoft.Maps.Search.IGeocodeRequestOptions = {
            where: query,
            userData: userData,
            count: 5,
            bounds: this.map.getBounds(),
            callback: function (r: any) {
                // PROBLEM: r undefined.
                if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) {
                    var topResult = r.results[0];
                    if (topResult) {
                        this.addPin(topResult.location);
                        $('#txtInput').focus().select();
                    }
                }
            },
            errorCallback: function (e: any) {
                // If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                alert("No results found.");
            }
        };

        // make the geocode request:
        this.searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
    }

    // .. other stuff in class
}


let geo: BMGeocode = new BMGeocode();

function onGeocodeClick() {
    geo.search();
}

$(function() {
    geo.loadMap();
    $('#geocode').click(onGeocodeClick);
})
```

I think I've detected the problem why it doesn't work, as the searchManager is always null or undefined. However I don't know how to solve it.

This line from the 'search' function works but doesn't seem to set the searchManager variable:

```
this.searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(this.map);
```

the searchManager is not set, so I can't make a request:

```
// make the geocode request:
    this.searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
```

How can this be solved in TypeScript?

**Update:** this doesn't seem to work either:

```
public search = () => {
            if (!this.searchManager) {
                var self = this;
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                    self.searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(self.map); // PROBLEM!!
  self.search(); 
                });

            } else {

            // remove any previous results from the map.
            this.map.entities.clear();

            // get the users query and geocode it.
            let query: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txtInput")).value;
            this.geocodeQuery(query);
        }
```

Comment: If serchManager is really never set, you should find some error in the console. Like a network error or a thrown exception during module load. On the other hand, it is possible you just have to wait more, as the module loader function is asynchronous.

Comment: i've tried to call search() recursive when searchManager was not set, but that also didn't work via this.search().

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in there and see if it runs `this.searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(this.map) ;`

Comment: it gets hit but it doesn't seem to set the searchManager variable from the root of my class, so when I call the geocode function later on, the searchManager is undefined.

Comment: To avoid the problem that you ran into, you should consider using the `noImplicitThis` flag, which will help flag places where you may be losing a reference to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

problem is that `this` variable doesn't refer to BMGeocode as you would expect but to the closure in which you are trying to use it. Try this instead:

```
var self = this
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
    self.searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(self.map) ; // PROBLEM: searchManager is never set?
});
```

Comment: It's not the case with arrow functions.

Comment: "search" is arrow function, but there is closure inside loadModule that isn't

Comment: @juFo Definitely should work. The error is still the same?

Comment: @juFo is the object actually being created? try assigning it to temporary variable first and check if that isnt null